# Problem launching working .sh script in cron using python, tensorflow

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, cron

I have a working script.sh `python /opt/facenet/src/train.py`. When I try to launch it in cron I get this error: `ImportError: No module named tensorflow`. I've tried this solution to find tensorflow location like this: 

`import tensorflow
tensorflow.__file__
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.pyc`

 So I've changed the path to the libraries, executed like this: `/home/user/anaconda3/lib/site-packages /opt/facenet/src/train.py` and got the following mistake: `/home/user/anaconda3/lib/site-packages: Permission denied`. I tried to fix it in many ways: chmod x+u and so on. But I still get the same mistake. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Check the interpreter being used to run the script (`which python` should let you know). Most probably it is not the interpreter you intend to run your scripts with. If you want to use the anaconda interpreter, the path will most likely be `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python`, so you must run your script using `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python /opt/facenet/src/train.py`

Comment: Of course, you must first check if the path I've mentioned is right using `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python --version`

Comment: @VigneshBayariR. I have already tried this, but without success, I had problems with Tensorflow version (cuda 9.0, tensorflow 1.12), I got this mistake: ` ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, I searched for solutions on Google but none of them helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15604). Apparently, downgrading Tensorflow solves it.

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow-gpu
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.4
```

Note: Make sure you're doing this in the environment you use to run the scripts.

Comment: It didn't work, I still get the same mistake: ` ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Check this thread: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15604). Apparently `pip3 uninstall tensorflow-gpu` and `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.4` in your virtualenv will solve the issue.